# Mandar formulario después de hacer clic en ok en el sweet alert

Tags: php, javascript, html, sweetalert

Buenas tardes vi esta solución en Internet sobre como hacer que el formulario no cargara antes de mostrar el sweetalert y funciona pero quisiera saber como hacer para que después de que se quite el sweetalert se mande el formulario.

```js
function validar(e) {
swal({title: "Buen trabajo!", 
text: "Clickeaste en el boton!", 
icon: "success"});
return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<form action="registrar.php" name="formulario_registro" method="post" onsubmit="return validar(event)">
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="btn-submit" value="Enviar">  
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente esto ya lo solucionaste, pero igual dejo mi aporte por si a alguien le sirve, aclaro que use `SweetAlert2`, primero agregue `event.preventDefault()` para evitar la redirección, luego en el `Swal.fire` añadi los botones para confirmar o no el `submit` del formulario y finalmente al confirmar el envío del formulario se hace el `submit`, quedaria asi:

```js
function enviar(){
event.preventDefault();

    Swal.fire({
    title: '¿Seguro de enviar el formulario?',
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Si',
    cancelButtonText: "No",
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
    document.formulario_registro.submit();
    }
    return false;
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.css">
<form action="registrar.php" name="formulario_registro" method="post" onsubmit="return enviar()">
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="btn-submit" value="Enviar">  
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que el mensaje quieres que se cierre despues de dar click al boton de ok, este codigo te serviria

```
function validar(e) {
    swal({
        title: "Buen trabajo!", 
        text: "Clickeaste en el boton!", 
        type: "success"
    }).then(function () {
        console.log("Despues de dar click en el boton, aqui llamarias al submit");
    })
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `Seria algo así?

function validar(e) {
    swal({
        title: "Buen trabajo!", 
        text: "Clickeaste en el boton!", 
        type: "success",
        confirmButtonText: "Ok"
    }).then(function envform() {
        console.log("Despues de dar click en el boton, aqui llamarias al submit");
        document.forms['freg'].submit();
    });
    return false;`

Comment: Exacto dentro del .then llamarias al submit de tu formulario, si te funciono

Comment: Funciona, pero envía el formulario y recarga la pagina antes de que termine de aparecer el sweetalert